# Can CKAN Extensions have controllers?

Tags: ckan

I am wondering if I can have controllers in a custom CKAN extension. If I can then how do I create routes to those controllers and the action functions in those controllers?

Thanks,
PK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. There is the [IRoutes Interface](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.3.5/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IRoutes) for CKAN extensions. The interface allows you to define routes to any controllers.

You can find an example at [2](https://github.com/okfn/ckan/blob/master/ckanext/resourceproxy/plugin.py#L46) which shows you how to connect a url in `before_map` and a controller in an extension.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I tried to implement the before_map() function following the pattern for setting the controller value (controller='ckanext.resourceproxy.controller:ProxyController) but I get module name not found error for the controller value. It seems I am not doing it right in specifying the path to the controller. Here is the path to the controller file(formtest.py) of the extension: ckanext-formtest\ckanext\formtest\controllers\formtest The name of the controller class in formtest.py file is FormtestController. Pl. let me know how I should be setting the value for controller.